# How to initialize optional UInt from optional Int?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, option-type

I want to convert an optional Int to an optional UInt:

```
let optionalNumber : Int?
//later in code
let optionalPositiveNumber = UInt(optionalNumber)
```

gives the error :

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Uint' with an argument list of type (Int?)
```

I can solve this by creating the following extension to UInt:

```
extension UInt {
   init?(_ number : Int?) {
       if let number = number {
           self = UInt(number)
       }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to convert `Int?` to `UInt?` without using extensions or condition check (if, guard) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `map` the optional:

```
var optionalNumber : Int?

//later in code
let optionalPositiveNumber = optionalNumber.map { UInt($0) }
```

From the [documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map)

> Evaluates the given closure when this Optional instance is not nil, passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.
>
> `func map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?`

So the result is an `UInt?` as requested, and is either `nil` or the converted signed number.

Note that the conversion will fail (and crash with a runtime exception)
if the given number is *negative.* If that is an issue, a better variant
might be

```
let optionalPositiveNumber = optionalNumber.flatMap { UInt(exactly: $0) }
```

which returns `nil` if the given number is `nil` or negative.

Answer (score 3):

You can create it with  **??**  and pass default value if it is nil

```
let optionalPositiveNumber = UInt(optionalNumber ?? 0)
```

So if your optionalNumber is nil it will be initialised with 0

**EDIT suggested by [vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630618/vacawama)**

```
let optionalPositiveNumber = UInt(exactly: optionalNumber ?? -1)
```

> if the value passed as `source` is not representable exactly, the result
>        is `nil`.

Comment: ?? is a condition also.

Comment: @U.Benlice It will be used in case of nil

Comment: Yes i know that. But he wants a solution without condition. First of all ?? is a condition. Also your solution not generates optional UInt. You are creating zero value on nil case.

Comment: @U.Benlice  That one line initialisation and it is fine for him since it has not if , guard and un necessary brackets .

Comment: `let optionalPositiveNumber = UInt(exactly: optionalNumber ?? -1)`.  `nil` will map to `nil`, negative numbers will be `nil`.

Comment: @vacawama I didn't get you sorry could you please explain

Comment: Try the code I suggested.  If original number is positive, you get a `UInt?` with the expected value.  If the original number is negative or `nil`, it will give you `nil`.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks I just read it, after that i don't think i need to use ?? operator it will by default handled by exactly ?

Comment: You still need `??` to unwrap the optional.  By using `-1` instead of `0` you cause it to convert a `nil` to `nil` which is the expected result.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks for explaining :)